# How to a start different activities by clicking a child view when using expandable recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using this expandable-recycler-view in Navigation Drawer to show categories can someone tell me how can I start different activities by clicking on different Items in the list.

I tried this

**ChildView Code:**

```
public class CategoryChildViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder implements view.OnClickListener
{
ImageView mSubCategoryImage;
TextView mSubCategoryTitle;

public CategoryChildViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    itemView.setClickable(true);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSubCategoryImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_category_thumbnail);
    mSubCategoryTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_category_title);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(InSightApp.getAppContext(), "The Item Clicked is: " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(InSightApp.getAppContext(), NavActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    InSightApp.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

By This I can start one activity on click event of a item in child list, since the position of the child view in the drop down list keeps on changing.
In this Image,Positional Index of Kids->Cloths is 4 i.e. Women 0, Men 1, Kids 2, Shoes 3, Cloths 4 [image: Image 1] 
In this Image,Positional Index of Kids->Cloths is 6 i.e. Women 0, Women->Shoes 1, Women->Cloths 2, Men 3, Kids 4, Kids->Shoes 5, Kids Cloths 6[image: Image 2] 
Because of variable positions I cannot use Switch cases to start different activities.

Thank you for reading this question